# How to implement this of a generic in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, syntax

This is just a Translation question.

But how do you write a the following C# code in vb.net

My problem is that i don't know how to rewrite the **this part** of the generic T.

C# code i want to translate

```
 public static void ShouldEqual<T>(this T actualValue, T expectedValue) { 
 Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue); }
```

My vb.net try

```
Public Shared Sub ShouldEqual(Of T)(ByVal actualvalue As T, ByVal expectedvalue As T)
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedvalue, actualvalue)
End Sub
```

Also any improvement to description of this problem would be welcome

The solution :

```
Public Module UnitTestHelpers
<Extension()>
Public Sub ShouldEqual(Of T)(ByVal actualvalue As T, ByVal expectedvalue As T)
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedvalue, actualvalue)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Extension attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is there a option to implement this by not using a module ?